# Why logout navlink doesn't work with localStorage?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to use localStorage in order to connect/disconnect users on my website. I tried to manage this with a condition on click on the navbar (it concerns the latest NavLink
component).In a middleware I recover the token (verified with a console.log). When the user wants to log out I would like to empty the token and display "LogIn" instead of "LogOut" . But that has no effect. The token is indeed null at the time of the click but impossible to disconnect. It is also impossible to connect again because the modal is not displayed because there is always "logout". Thank you very much for your help!
AppHeader (index.js)

```
// import Bootsrap-react's components
import {
  Container,
  Navbar,
  Nav,
  Modal,
  Button,
  Form,
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import logo from 'src/assets/images/logo.png';
import { fetchAllEvents } from '../../actions/events';
import { setSelectedRegionId } from '../../actions/regions';
import { setSelectedGenreId } from '../../actions/genres';
import { changeEmail, changePassword, logIn } from '../../actions/user';
import './appHeader.scss';

const AppHeader = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const emailValue = useSelector((state) => state.user.email);
  const passwordValue = useSelector((state) => state.user.password);
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  const callLogin = () => {
    let isLogged;
    if (token !== null) {
      isLogged = 'Logout';
    }
    else {
      isLogged = 'Log In';
    }
    return isLogged;
  };
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setShow(true);
  const logOut = () => localStorage.setItem('token', null);
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar id="mainNav" expand="lg">
        <Container id="navbar-container">
          <LinkContainer to="/">
            <Navbar.Brand> <img src={logo} alt="logo" height="60" />
            </Navbar.Brand>
          </LinkContainer>
          <LinkContainer to="/">
            <Nav.Link>
              <h2 className="navbar-title">Concert'o</h2>
            </Nav.Link>
          </LinkContainer>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav " placement="right">
            <Nav className="flex-grow-1 justify-content-evenly">
              <LinkContainer
                to="/"
                onClick={() => {
                  dispatch(setSelectedGenreId());
                  dispatch(setSelectedRegionId());
                }}
              >
                <Nav.Link className="navlink-header">Accueil</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/genres">
                <Nav.Link className="navlink-header">Genres</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/regions">
                <Nav.Link className="navlink-header">Regions</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer
                to="/tous-les-evenements"
                onClick={() => {
                  dispatch(setSelectedGenreId());
                  dispatch(setSelectedRegionId());
                  dispatch(fetchAllEvents());
                }}
              >
                <Nav.Link className="navlink-header">Tous les événements</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <Nav.Link
                className="navlink-header "
                onClick={() => {
                  if (token !== null) {
                    dispatch(logOut());
                  }
                  else {
                    dispatch(handleOpen());
                  }
                }}
              >{callLogin()}
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Me connecter</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Form>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="email"
                placeholder="name@example.com"
                autoFocus
                email={emailValue}
                onChange={(event) => {
                  // console.log(event.target.value);
                  dispatch(changeEmail(event.target.value));
                }}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group
              className="mb-3"
              controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1"
            >
              <Form.Label>Mot de passe</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="password"
                password={passwordValue}
                onChange={(event) => {
                  // console.log(event.target.value);
                  dispatch(changePassword(event.target.value));
                }}

              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button
            variant="secondary"
            onClick={() => {
              dispatch(logIn());
              dispatch(handleClose());
            }}
          >
            Valider
          </Button>
          <LinkContainer
            to="/inscription"
          >
            <Button onClick={handleClose} variant="primary">
              Pas encore inscrit ? Cliquez ici
            </Button>
          </LinkContainer>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </div>

  );
};
export default AppHeader;
```

USER REDUCER

```
import { CHANGE_EMAIL, CHANGE_PASSWORD, SAVE_USER_DATA } from '../actions/user';

export const initialState = {

  email: '',
  password: '',
  username: '',
  token: null,
  errorMessage: '',
};

const user = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_EMAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        email: action.value,
      };
    case CHANGE_PASSWORD:
      return {
        ...state,
        password: action.value,
      };
    case SAVE_USER_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        username: action.nickname,
        token: action.token,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default user;
```

Comment: ``dispatch()`` expects an action object https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-2-concepts-data-flow#dispatch . Can you share your code for your user reducer ?

Comment: of course ! I added it ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Why the `token` isn't `null`

[You can only store a **string** in `localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#description), so when you set it to `null` and check later if the value is `null`, the answer is no because `localStorage` is now equal to the **string** `"null"`, not `null`.

What you can do instead is removing the token altogether :

```js
localStorage.removeItem("token");
```

Then simply check if `token` exists :

```js
let isLogged;
if (token) {
  isLogged = "Logout";
} else {
  isLogged = "Log In";
}
return isLogged;
```

You can also shorten your code with the following :

```js
return token ? 'Logout' : 'Log In'
```

##### Moreover

You are using `dispatch`, which is a function for updating the `store` by **passing in an action object**, however `dispatch(logOut());`, `dispatch(handleOpen());` and `dispatch(handleClose());` are not passing in an object, these functions don't return anything. Meaning you might (and should) run into errors because of this, since that's an improper use of the `dispatch` function.

[Read more about *dispatch* here](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-2-concepts-data-flow#dispatch).